# Writing text to console buffer

Tags: vb.net, buffer, windows-console, wine

I am just learning programming, so please be understanding :)
I am writing an application that needs to send text data to another console program. I was successful with `SendMessage()`, but unfortunately with Wine (on linux) it is not supported for console applications.

So I found a function that is supported. This is `WriteConsoleInput()`.

Here is my code, could someone indicate why it doesn't work?

```
Public Declare Function AttachConsole Lib "kernel32" (ByVal ProcessID As Long) As Boolean
Private Declare Function GetStdHandle Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal nStdHandle As Int32) As IntPtr
Declare Function WriteConsoleInputW Lib "kernel32" Alias "WriteConsoleInputW" (ByVal hConsoleInput As Integer, ByVal lpBuffer As String, ByVal nNumberOfCharsToWrite As Integer, ByRef lpNumberOfCharsWritten As Integer) As Integer
Declare Function WriteConsoleInputA Lib "kernel32" Alias "WriteConsoleInputA" (ByVal hConsoleInput As Integer, ByVal lpBuffer As String, ByVal nNumberOfCharsToWrite As Integer, ByRef lpNumberOfCharsWritten As Integer) As Integer
Declare Function SetConsoleTitle Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "SetConsoleTitleA" (lpConsoleTitle As String) As Boolean


Private Const STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE As Long = -11&
Private Const STD_INPUT_HANDLE As Long = -10&
Private Const STD_ERROR_HANDLE As Long = -12&
Private Const INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE As Long = -1&

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim titleStr As String = "Test"
    Dim textToWrite As Char() = CType("test", Char())
    Dim stdIN As Integer
    Dim stdOUT As Integer
    Dim charwritten As Integer = 0
    Dim ret As Integer

    If ReturnCMDProcessID() = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("CMD off")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    AttachConsole(ReturnCMDProcessID())
    stdIN = CInt(GetStdHandle(CInt(STD_INPUT_HANDLE)))

    stdOUT = CInt(GetStdHandle(CInt(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)))


    ret = WriteConsoleInputA(stdIN, textToWrite, textToWrite.Length, charwritten)



    SetConsoleTitle(titleStr)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the "built-in" way to do this?

`System.Console`:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console?view=netframework-4.8

And in particular `Console.In`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.in?view=netframework-4.8

And `Console.Out`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.out?view=netframework-4.8

I also just noticed you are setting the title, that is as simple as `Console.Title = "My Title"`

Comment: The OP's code sports a `Button1_Click` (WinForms app), which calls `AttachConsole()` (VB6 fashion, + declaring both the `W` and `A` version of *some* Win32 functions, bypassing the automatic function selection feature). The `ProcessId` passed to `AttachConsole` is undefined (and it's not `-1`), the return value is discarded so there's no call to `GetLatsError` or a `Marshal` version of it, `FreeConsole` is not declared, etc.

Comment: "VB6 fashion, + declaring both the W and A version of some Win32 functions, bypassing the automatic function selection feature)."    -   As I said, I'm new. For now, I'm mainly looking for information on forums and that's how these functions were implemented.

You are probably right, but the console is well hooked up to the process because its title changes with SetConsoleTitle ().

"FreeConsole is not declared, etc"  -  Again, you are right. I just declared it.

Now I'm only interested in why WriteCon doesn't want to work. It returns correctly 1, and the number of characters entered.

Comment: This question is tagged `vb.net`.  If the tag was not correct, then my answer is not valid since I linked to VB.NET references.  @mrharibo, is this VB.NET or VB6?

Comment: That is VB.NET. Thaks @tcarvin for trying to help, but I really want to use this function.